# Access ADAM instance with JXplorer

Tags: authentication, adam

Is it possible to access an ADAM instance with CA JXplorer?
I have an ADAM up and running, it could be accessed by ADAM ADSI Edit with my own Windows account and password.
JXplorer, on the other hand, uses UserDN for authentication. What should be my UserDN then?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify your userDN as:

```
username@yourdomain.org
```

Where "yourdomain.org" is the fully qualified domain name of the Active Directory domain that your user account lives in.

(I should add that this is an AD specific thing - no such equivalent exists for OpenLDAP).

Answer (score 0):

Yes

1. you create user object by the user object class.
2. Set password the new user(use ADSI Editor).
3. Use userid : full DN of user

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. But I just ran into the same issue today. Here is what I ended up doing.
In Windows ADSI, I opened the instance's configuration.
Double clicked - CN=Directory Service,CN=Windows NT,CN=Services,CN=Configuration
Then changed msds-other-settings attribute to ADAMAllowADAMSecurityPrincipalsInConfigPartition=1

Then created a user object in the cn=Roles. Reset the user's password. Then copied the user's DN (e.g. CN=tuser1,CN=Roles,CN=Configuration,CN={752D29BC-24E4-45E1-AE1E-855A812848DD} )
added it to msds-memberOfTransitive attribute of cn=Administrators.

Now I can connect to it with jXplorer where I use CN=tuser1,CN=Roles,CN=Configuration,CN={752D29BC-24E4-45E1-AE1E-855A812848DD} and password for my User DN/Password for username+password connection.

I haven't been able to create new users/password or organizations with jxplorer, but at least I can see the most common attributes of the existing users and orgs.